# Print and use the data from two files simultaenously

Tags: perl, file, file-handling

#### pdb1.pdb

```
ATOM    709  CA  THR    25     -29.789  33.001  72.164  1.00  0.00
ATOM    711  CB  THR    25     -29.013  31.703  72.370  1.00  0.00
ATOM    734  CG  THR    25     -29.838  30.458  72.573  1.00  0.00
ATOM    768  CE  THR    25     -28.541  28.330  71.361  1.00  0.00
```

#### pdb2.pdb

```
ATOM    765  N   ALA    25     -30.838  33.150  73.195  1.00  0.00
ATOM    764  N   LEU    26     -29.457  33.193  69.767  1.00  0.00
ATOM    783  N   VAL    27     -30.286  31.938  66.438  1.00  0.00
ATOM    798  N   GLY    28     -28.076  30.044  64.519  1.00  0.00
```

#### output desired

```
709 CA 765 N 1.477 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -30.838 33.150 73.195
709 CA 764 N 2.427 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -29.457 33.193 69.767
709 CA 783 N 5.844 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -30.286 31.938 66.438
```

and so on.

The content from `pdb1.pdb` and `pdb2.pdb` is to read values in column 2,3,6,7 and 8 and then using column 6,7,8 do distance calculations.

I tried with this but the output is not getting printed.

#### Perl

```perl
open( f1, "pdb1.pdb" or die $! );
open( f2, "pdb2.pdb" or die $! );

while ( ( $line1 = <$f1> ) and ( $line2 = <$f2> ) ) {

    @splitted = split( ' ', $line1 );

    my @fields = split / /, $line1;

    print $fields[1], "\n";

    my $atom1 = @{ [ $line1 =~ m/\S+/g ] }[2];
    my $no1   = @{ [ $line1 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[3];

    my $x1 = @{ [ $line1 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[6];
    my $y1 = @{ [ $line1 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[7];
    my $z1 = @{ [ $line1 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[8];

    my $atom2 = @{ [ $line2 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[2];
    my $no2   = @{ [ $line2 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[3];

    my $x2 = @{ [ $line2 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[6];
    my $y2 = @{ [ $line2 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[7];
    my $z2 = @{ [ $line2 =~ m/\w+/g ] }[8];

    print $atom1;

    for ( $f1, $f2 ) {
        print $atom1 $no1 $x1 $y1 $z1 $atom2 $no2 $x2 $y2 $z2 "\n";
    }
}

close( $f1 );
close( $f2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has lot of syntactical errors. I had made some changes to your code and this will get you started to what you want.

First of all `use strict` and `use warnings` by this way you would have already got a lot of noise removed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $f1, "pdb1.pdb") or die $!;    
open(my $f2, "pdb2.pdb") or die $!;

while(defined(my $line1 = <$f1>) and defined(my $line2 = <$f2>))
{
   # print "Iam here";
   my  @splitted = split(' ',$line1);

    my @fields = split / /, $line1;

    #print $fields[1], "\n";

    my $atom1 = @{[$line1 =~ m/\S+/g]}[2];
    my $no1   = @{[$line1 =~ m/\w+/g]}[3];

    my $x1 = @{[$line1 =~ m/\w+/g]}[6];
    my $y1 = @{[$line1 =~ m/\w+/g]}[7];
    my $z1 = @{[$line1 =~ m/\w+/g]}[8];

    my $atom2 = @{[$line2 =~ m/\w+/g]}[2];
    my $no2   = @{[$line2 =~ m/\w+/g]}[3];

    my $x2 = @{[$line2 =~ m/\w+/g]}[6];
    my $y2 = @{[$line2 =~ m/\w+/g]}[7];
    my $z2 = @{[$line2 =~ m/\w+/g]}[8];

    #print $atom1;

    for ($f1, $f2) { 
        print "$atom1 $no1 $x1 $y1 $z1 $atom2 $no2 $x2 $y2 $z2 \n"; 
    }
}

close ($f1);
close ($f2);
```

Now coming to your question, your expected output seems to be different from what you are doing in your logic. You are looping two files simultaneously which will do a one one one iteration rather than each line from file1 with all lines in file2. So I think you might need to look at looping part.

And the next thing you need to know is about column splitting.

```
@splitted = split(' ',$line1);
```

if you split a line in the above mentioned way you get all columns in the array. SO now your column1 is in zeroth index, column2 in first index and so on.

SO to get first column you should do

```
my $col1 = @splitted[0];
```

If you are using those regexs just for getting columns then its not needed as you are splitting those already and you have each column indpendently in the array.

**Update:**

The problem that you were getting was that you were using filehandles to iterate which is causing the issue.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $f1, "<pdb1.pdb") or die "$!" ;
open(my $f2, "<pdb2.pdb") or die "$!" ; 
my @in1 = <$f1>;
my @in2 = <$f2>;

foreach my $file1 (@in1) {       #use array to iterate
    chomp($file1);
    #print "File1 $file1\n";
    my $atomno1=(split " ", $file1)[1];
    my $atomname1=(split " ", $file1)[2];
    my $xx=(split " ", $file1)[5];
    my $yy=(split " ", $file1)[6];
    foreach my  $file2(@in2) {

        chomp($file2);
        #print "File2 $file2\n";


        my $atomno2=(split " ", $file2)[1]; 
        my $atomname2=(split " ", $file2)[2];
        my $x=(split " ", $file2)[5];
        my $y=(split " ", $file2)[6];
        my $dis=sqrt((($x-$xx)*($x-$xx))+ (($y-$yy)*($y-$yy)));
        print "$atomno1 $atomname1 $atomno2 $atomname2 $dis $xx $yy $x $y\n" ; 
    }
    #$file1++;
} 
close ($f1);
```

Comment: _open(f1, "<pdb1.pdb") or die "$!" ;
open(f2, "<pdb2.pdb") or die "$!" ;

foreach $file1 (<f1>) {
my $atomno1=(split " ", $file1)[1];
my $atomname1=(split " ", $file1)[2];
my $xx=(split " ", $file1)[5];
my $yy=(split " ", $file1)[6];
while ($file2=<f2>)
{
 my $atomno2=(split " ", $file2)[1];
 my $atomname2=(split " ", $file2)[2];
 my $x=(split " ", $file2)[5];
 my $y=(split " ", $file2)[6];
  my $dis=sqrt((($x-$xx)*($x-$xx))+ (($y-$yy)*($y-$yy)));
print "$atomno1 $atomname1  $atomno2 $atomname2   $dis  $xx  $yy $x  $y\n" ;
}
$file1++;
}
close (f1); _

Comment: Please explain @ruchika

Comment: I am not getting how to print the said thing as code (script)

Comment: but it's just running for one time for file1 is getting read only once.. What i need is to run the program for one line in file one versus each line in file 2, till the end of file 1. Right now only file 1 first line with each line of file 2 is running. Do u know how to make the code run foreach line in file1

Comment: @ruchika did that help?

Comment: Do you really need to split every line five times? And why are you ignoring the z coordinates in column eight in your second attempt?

Comment: @Borodin Yes I know that didnt want to change the OP's code and corrected just the required part as stated in comment by OP

Comment: @ Nagaraju ... yes it did! thanks for your help and guidance sir.

Comment: @ruchika if the answer helped you, you may upvote, accept it

Comment: @Nagaraju... I already tried.. but as per policy persons with 15 + reputations can upvote only

Comment: @ruchika oh sorry about that, I didnt notice

Answer (score 1):

It's probably simplest to read both files into memory unless they're enormous

This solution calls subroutine `read_file` to build an array of hashes of all five fields of interest from each file. It then calculates the delta and reformats the data for output

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $f1 = read_file('file1.txt');
my $f2 = read_file('file2.txt');

for my $r1 ( @$f1 ) {

    for my $r2 ( @$f2 ) {

        my ($dx, $dy, $dz) = map { $r1->{$_} - $r2->{$_} } qw/ x y z /;
        my $delta = sqrt( $dx * $dx + $dy * $dy + $dz * $dz );

        my @rec = (
            @{$r1}{qw/ id name /},
            @{$r2}{qw/ id name /},
            sprintf('%5.3f', $delta),
            @{$r1}{qw/ x y z /},
            @{$r2}{qw/ x y z /},
        );

        print "@rec\n";
    }
}

sub read_file {
    my ($file_name) = @_;

    open my $fh, '<', $file_name or die qq{Unable to open "$file_name" for input: $!};

    my @records;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /\S/;
        my %record;
        @record{qw/ id name x y z /} = (split)[1,2,5,6,7];
        push @records, \%record;
    }

    \@records;
}
```

#### output

```
709 CA 765 N 1.478 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -30.838 33.150 73.195
709 CA 764 N 2.427 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -29.457 33.193 69.767
709 CA 783 N 5.845 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -30.286 31.938 66.438
709 CA 798 N 8.374 -29.789 33.001 72.164 -28.076 30.044 64.519
711 CB 765 N 2.471 -29.013 31.703 72.370 -30.838 33.150 73.195
711 CB 764 N 3.032 -29.013 31.703 72.370 -29.457 33.193 69.767
711 CB 783 N 6.072 -29.013 31.703 72.370 -30.286 31.938 66.438
711 CB 798 N 8.079 -29.013 31.703 72.370 -28.076 30.044 64.519
734 CG 765 N 2.938 -29.838 30.458 72.573 -30.838 33.150 73.195
734 CG 764 N 3.937 -29.838 30.458 72.573 -29.457 33.193 69.767
734 CG 783 N 6.327 -29.838 30.458 72.573 -30.286 31.938 66.438
734 CG 798 N 8.255 -29.838 30.458 72.573 -28.076 30.044 64.519
768 CE 765 N 5.646 -28.541 28.330 71.361 -30.838 33.150 73.195
768 CE 764 N 5.199 -28.541 28.330 71.361 -29.457 33.193 69.767
768 CE 783 N 6.348 -28.541 28.330 71.361 -30.286 31.938 66.438
768 CE 798 N 7.069 -28.541 28.330 71.361 -28.076 30.044 64.519
```